# How to incrase social media for Android Application and website

Tags: facebook, social-networking, ads, populate

As I am new for advertising on social media .

I want to spread up my `Android application` and `Website` in less time to all over the world. 
or there any websites , viral distribution to all over the world .
As it is silly question please don't ignore it , even i searched in Google but i not get full idea for on advertising and viral marketing to all over the world

thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

for fast promotion, you can try BLACKHAT SEO, but i wont recommend it, coz once google see's doing SEO wrongly, it will penalize and ur website will never rank on top page..
regards

Comment: hoo k.. thank you ... then how can i reach to the people... also how they are know new product came in world.

Comment: http://blog.crushpath.com/2013/09/how-to-promote-a-product-5-of-the-best-most-inexpensive-ways-to-promote/

Comment: http://www.forbes.com/sites/ilyapozin/2012/04/11/10-proven-ways-to-market-your-website/

Comment: thank you so much for your guides...  this what i want and more links and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

try good SEO stuff, be careful that google wont penalize your website.

Comment: I fallowed total SEO points... that is i want my new product or application how to reach to the people. i want spread up my App and website

Comment: for new websites or promoting your application through social media is greatly done by SEO people, lot of stuffs involved in SEO, google it...

Comment: yes .. am using social media also . but i cannot to reach to people. i want more traffic and downloads for my app. So please provide some links and some suggestions

Comment: hmmm ok, how many pages have google crawled your websites, at seo, target some external backlink, like blogs/ forums and submit..

Comment: everything cannot happen overnight, coz they are thousand of competitors striving to hit on top of google search engine...they are many tools also..analyze what your website is lacking first..try google analytics..